# Get the sum() in a WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have this SQL, but it dosen't work correctly.

```
SELECT     [Customer No_], SUM(Amount) AS SumDebitor, [Posting Date]
FROM         dbo.[3S Company A_S$Detailed Cust_ Ledg_ Entry]
WHERE     ([Posting Date] <= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-04-10 00:00:00', 102))
GROUP BY [Customer No_], [Posting Date]
HAVING      ([Customer No_] = '45')
```

What i want, is get the total SUM() of all posts from before my date.
Right now i get more that 5000 results, sum of everyday.

Can someone help me on the right way?

Comment: In general the WHERE clause is for regular conditions, and the HAVING clause is for aggregate function conditions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should not have posting date with grouping (if you do posting date grouping .. you will get all posting date sum independently)

and moreover having clause is not required .. your query should be like following

```
SELECT     [Customer No_], SUM(Amount) AS SumDebitor
FROM         dbo.[3S Company A_S$Detailed Cust_ Ledg_ Entry]
WHERE     ([Posting Date] <= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-04-10 00:00:00', 102))
And  ([Customer No_] = '45')
GROUP BY [Customer No_]
```

or as below (if you need count for all customer)

```
SELECT     [Customer No_], SUM(Amount) AS SumDebitor
FROM         dbo.[3S Company A_S$Detailed Cust_ Ledg_ Entry]
WHERE     ([Posting Date] <= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-04-10 00:00:00', 102))
GROUP BY [Customer No_]
```